# Plotting the sequence $u_n = 2u_{n-1}-u_{n-2}$: $u_0=1$ and $u_1=2$ in WolframAlpha

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I plot

Plotting the sequence

> $$u_n = 2u_{n-1}-u_{n-2}.$$

with starting values $u_0=1$ and $u_1=2$ in Wolframalpha ? Or any graphing calculator.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to plot it?

Comment: @DanielFischer visualisation

Comment: Aha. I don't know how to make Wolfram Alpha plot it, but I can tell you that $u_n = n+1$, so you can visualise that even without plot.

Comment: @DanielFischer But how did you get there? Do you know how to put it on any graphing calculator?

Comment: Do you mean $u_n = 2u_{n-1} + u_{n-2}?$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Of course.

Comment: That wasn't clear, and that's where Daniel's comment came from

Comment: Oh wait never mind

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer on Wolfram Alpha like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%5Bn%5D%20=%202%20u%5Bn-1%5D%20-%20u%5Bn-2%5D,%20u%5B0%5D%20=%201,%20u%5B1%5D%20=%202).  Alternatively, if you have a graphing calculator, you can find the sequence using the sequence graphing mode, as [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJzbdKj2NDw) demonstrates.

Recursive definitions like this can be resolved fairly easily using either generating functions or the $Z$-transform.

EDIT: Apparently, my link for WA doesn't work for some people for some reason.  When I [follow my earlier link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%5Bn%5D%20=%202%20u%5Bn-1%5D%20-%20u%5Bn-2%5D,%20u%5B0%5D%20=%201,%20u%5B1%5D%20=%202), I get the following from WA:

[image: Wolfram Alpha sequence stuff]

I don't know why it wouldn't work for anyone.

Comment: "Wolfram|Alpha doesn't know how to interpret your input." says Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: @LordSoth I've added a screenshot of what it shows when I click the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up in GeoGebra's spreadsheet like this:

http://web.geogebra.org/?command=FillColumn[1,1..20];B1=1;B2=2;B3=2B2-B1;C1=(A1,B1);C2=(A2,B2);C3=(A3,B3);#spreadsheet

and then select cells B3 and C3 together and copy down (by dragging the blue square) to plot more points